# SQL configuration for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, sql, content

We are migrating SharePoint 2010 data(100GB) from one company A to company B(After acquisition) creating a new SharePoint 2010 farm.

Company B also has around 100GB data in SP 2007 version which will eventually Migrated to SP 2010 farm.

When we plan for capacity what should be the SQL space?

Answer (score 2):

you have to think about the many factors to make a decision.

- Current Usage (you have 200GB)
- What type of data will be stored in the SharePoint and their retention
- Plan recylebin cleanup or configure it properly.
- Future growth short term and long term.
- there is one formula from MSFT.

  Database size = ((D × V) × S) + (10 KB × (L + (V × D)))

  - D = expected number of documents,
  - V = expected number of versions
  - S = average size of the document
  - L = number of list items, and 10KB is the expected metadata on each
    document.

I would start with 300 GB then calculate the rest of the factor